# Can a lambda expression be declared and invoked at the same time in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda

In VB.NET, a lambda expression can be declared and invoked on the same line:

```
'Output 3
Console.WriteLine((Function(num As Integer) num + 1)(2))
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: The question is, when is this ever useful?

Comment: This is such a JavaScript concept, but we use it there because there's no other way to limit scope, whereas in C# there is.

Comment: I needed to do this inside an object initializer to avoid declaring a function body elsewhere. However, for some reason, I couldn't do it with the same syntax as in the answers above when trying to remove all input arguments. :( E.g. this didn't work : `(Func<byte>)(() => (byte)0))()`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler a specific delegate type. For example, you could *cast* the lambda expression:

```
Console.WriteLine(((Func<int, int>)(x => x + 1))(2));
```

EDIT: Or yes, you can use a delegate creation expression as per Servy's answer:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Func<int, int>(i => i + 1)(2));
```

Note that this isn't *really* a normal constructor call - it's special syntax for delegate creation which *looks* like a regular constructor call. Still clever though :)

You can make it *slightly* cleaner with a helper class:

```
public static class Functions
{
    public static Func<T> Of<T>(Func<T> input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    public static Func<T1, TResult> Of<T1, TResult>
        (Func<T1, TResult> input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    public static Func<T1, T2, TResult> Of<T1, T2, TResult>
        (Func<T1, T2, TResult> input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

... then:

```
Console.WriteLine(Functions.Of<int, int>(x => x + 1)(2));
```

Or:

```
Console.WriteLine(Functions.Of((int x) => x + 1)(2));
```

Comment: `Of<T1, T2, TResult>` and  `Of<T>(Func<T> input)` weren't used..?

Comment: @Fulproof: Not in this particular case, no. But I'd basically include as many variantions as you want to support.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet, I'd appreciate any more exercises especially such short and clear (in yet complicated for me syntax areas). I also wanted to ask why a helper class makes lambda expressions cleaner? they look either the same or more complicated (taking into account  difficult yet to me  `Func<>`, lambda expressions)?

Comment: @Fulproof: They allow for type inference, even if you're projecting to anonymous classes.

Answer (score 33):

```
Console.WriteLine(new Func<int, int>(i => i + 1)(2));
```

Uses a few less parentheses to use the `Func`'s constructor than a cast.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, though it's messy:

```
Console.WriteLine(((Func<int, int>) (num => num + 1))(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind or, you would have to use the Func object :

```
 var square = new Func<double, double>(d => d*d)(2);
 Console.WriteLine(square);
```

Comment: If you're going to use a separate variable, you can make it cleaner than that by moving the type to the declaration instead of using `var`.